# How to set the python searching directory of data file in another sub-folder in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Here my project has folder alignment as follows:

```
 myProject:
    ---------
     main.py
 -------------
     folder1:
         test.py
 --------------
     folder2:
         lib.py
         __init__.py
       ---------------
         folder_for_data:
              data_file1
              data_file2
```

So how to specify the searching path if I want to open the `data_file1` in the `test.py` scripts ? Actually, I can successfully open the data file in `main.py` by directly specifying the path as `folder2/folder_for_data/data_file1`. However, as I do the same thing in `test.py`, PyCharm tells me there is no such file or directory. I already add `myProject` to Content Root in pycharm, but why I can't open the file as I specified above.

By the way, I can import modules in lib.py with `from folder2.lib import module`. I guess if there are any tricks required to specify searching root path for data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, this question is independent of PyCharm. It's mostly about how to import modules and load data files in Python using relative paths.

Importing modules is different than opening data files, for quite a number of reasons. It is affected by: the working directory that you run Python from, the PYTHONPATH, use of Python 2 vs. Python 3.4+, whether you have setup your work as a Python package, and whether you have an **init**.py in place.

For the data file, my suggestion: use Python's facilities to find the directory of the running script, then use the path modules to make a directory relative to that.